# accessing url using machine name not working but local/websites works

Tags: php, iis

I am try to access a website using machineName/WebsiteName which i am not able to access but localhost/WebsiteName works .ANy guess what can go wrong.It says 
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Although all the resources are present and static content is enabled.Its a php website with iis server configuration
Thanks,

Comment: Could be it has a Firewall and port 80 is closed to all but localhost

Comment: where is your code? we cannot guess for you.

Comment: try using UNC for your pathing. and post your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. check host file entry on server. Path for host file is C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
2. Make sure that you are using same host name in url which is there in host file.
3. Check firewall.